# Tolerance criteria Brent's method

Tags: algorithm, math, root, numerical-methods, modelica

Stop criteria for Brent's method is

```
if abs(m) <= tol or fb == 0.0 then    // root found (interval is small enough) 
    found := true;
```

However, what if `abs(m)` reaches below said tolerance but the value of `f(b)` is no where close to zero? Will this case be considered as failed to converge or successfully converged? I can see that `abs(m) < tolerance`, i.e. `|b-a| < tolerance`, but the value of the function is not equal to zero or anywhere close. Isn't the whole point of Brent's method to find the root of a function such that `f(b) == 0.0` or below a certain tolerance?

Is it always the case that when `|b-a| < tolerance` convergence is achieved even though the value of the function is not close to zero, i.e. below given tolerance?

Answer (score 6):

If `r` is the root then you want to approximate `r` (not `f(r)`) to within a given tolerance, which is exactly what is happening here. It is of course possible that the graph of `f` is almost vertical at this point so that if `b` is your approximation `f(b)` isn't close to `0`. If that happens, you need a smaller tolerance. For most applications, knowing a root to 6 decimal places is more than adequate, but if your application involves a function whose values can change dramatically in response to a change in the 7th decimal place you will of course run into problems. This is the reason why in a numerical analysis course, expressions for the error in the method involve bounds on the derivatives. You need some sort of smoothness assumption to get reasonable results.

Comment: Yes its true that i want to approximate 'r' since 'r' is the root but I want the root of the function such that f(r) = 0 which is the whole point of using a method like Brent. The problem is the tolerance stop criterion used in Brent's method. It stops iterating once abs(m) <= tol or f(r) = 0.

Comment: But I have found a scenario where abs(m) has reached below given tolerance but the value of the function i.e., f(root) = 5000 i.e., the function is nowhere close to zero as required. In such a case does it mean Brent hasn't converged? I have set a tolerance of 1e-8. This should be enough to overcome rounding off errors right?

Comment: Another thing I want to point out here is that using fixed point iterative scheme for the same function finds a solution root 'r' such that f(r) is below 1e-8. So what could be the reason for Brent not converging?

Comment: If the method with tolerance 1e-8 returns a root with f(root) = 5000, then you are dealing with a function so wild near the root that ordinary numerical methods are likely to fail. Perhaps there is some way to rescale the problem. If the function is continuous then it must be true that the true root you are seeking to approximate is within 1e-8 of your computed root.

Comment: I'm actually trying to solve the Blade Element Momentum equations for a wind turbine. Since there a lot of constraints and variables this seems quite possible. However, I just wanted to ask "What is the criteria to decide that Brent's method failed to converge?" Because there are cases where abs(m) has reached below 1e-8 tolerance but the value of the function i.e., f(root) is not below 1e-8. Can one say that Brent's method failed to converge for all such cases?

Comment: The tolerance applies to `r` not `f(r)`. The idea is that by definition we know that at a root `f(root) = 0`, so we don't need to approximate the value `0`, we already know it. What we do need is to approximate `r` to within a given tolerance. You have done so, though perhaps in this case it isn't good enough. "Convergence" is a limiting notion, not really directly relevant. With arbitrary precision arithmetic, Brent's method will get closer and closer, but if you are seeing this sort of thing within 1e-8, I would distrust any numerical result.

Comment: You might want to ask a question on [mathematics.se], but if you do so give a little more details about the situation. The problem that you are describing probably has a standard solution in numerical analysis.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to see a plot of the function that you are trying to find the root of!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628219/brents-method-convergence-criteria

Answer (score 3):

Brent's method is a bracketing method, which means it keeps a bracketing interval, which means two points with opposite sign in their function value, during the iteration. It follows that in that interval of length `m` there is a sign change, thus there is, by the intermediate value theorem, an "exact" root close to `b` with a distance not larger than `m`.

Not exactly "exact" because you are evaluating a numerical function. If one zooms in on the interval on the segment transitioning from clearly positive to clearly negative (or v.v.), the actual graph of the numerical evaluation might look rather fuzzy, like for the expanded Wilkinson polynomial,

[image: plot of fuzzy magnification]

from [example and plot using expanded W.-pol.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3021704/115115).

On the other extreme, the numerical function may not appear fuzzy under magnification, but then it will be piecewise constant and may not have a point with value zero,

[image: plot of piecewise constant magnification]

(horizontal scale in parts of `1e-14`) from [example and plot using factorized W.-pol.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626069/3088138).