# Bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

I want to make a Python program that will run a bisection method to determine the root of:

```
2*3.14*(x+0.25)**2 + 2*3.14*(x+0.25)*(1000/(3.14*x**2))
```

The Bisection method is a numerical method for estimating the roots of a polynomial f(x).

Are there any available pseudocode, algorithms or libraries I could use to tell me the answer?

Comment: Please use a search engine. Or do some work yourself. This is the most basic root-finding method, one could call it "intelligent guessing" if any guessing were involved. // Your function is not a polynomial. // It might help if you review the "Intermediate value theorem" and how this relates to the bisection method.

Comment: Could tou clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code. Your function has a root in the interval [-1,1].

```python
import numpy as np
a=-1 
b=0.9
tol = 1e-6
itr=50

def bisection (a,b,tol,itr):
    fa=f(a)
    for k in range(1,itr):
        c=(a+b)/2
        fc=f(c)
        if(abs(fc)<tol):
            break

        if (fa*fc)<0:
            b=c
        else:
            a=c
            fa=fc
    return c

def f(x):
    y=2*3.14*(x+0.25)**2+2*3.14*(x+0.25)*1000/(3.14*x**2)
    return y 

bisection (a,b,tol,itr)
```

Comment: You should make the error checking relative, `abs(fc) < tol*abs(f0)` or so, where `f0` is set to the `fa` at the start. Otherwise the usual break condition is `abs(b-a)<tol`, but that is semi-addressed with the maximal iteration count.

Comment: ````abs(b-a)<tol is the check on the interval length whereas above check is for the function value at the mid point. If mid point is the root, then f(c) should be zero. or numerically should be less than <tol

Comment: Try that with the Wilkinson polynomial, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235831/tolerance-criteria-brents-method/61237587#61237587. The jump in function value from one floating point argument to the next can be arbitrarily large. Thus you can get jumps from -770 to 750 with nothing in-between.